# Angular Changing subject in ngOnInit of a child that Parent component is subscribed to doesnt affect Parent

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use Angular 9
I have Parent and Child components and service which stores `BehaviorSubject`. All components have `OnPush` strategy

1. Parent component uses async pipe to subscribe on that service subject
2. Parent component contains child component
3. Child component changes that service subject at the beginning of its lifecycle (ngOnInit)

With this steps parent will not react immediately after child changes the observable.
Here is reproducible [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cyvj6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) . Parent will not be updated until you focus input of a child, for instance.

I have debugged the process and see that `tick` function is called after async pipe does `markForCheck`. So I cannot understand why then the view is not updated?
I notice that if I Change strategy back to `Default` the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` will appear, so it looks like that this change happens outside of main Change Detection process.

Can you help me what is the problem with current approach and what is the correct way to make changes like I described?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in data flow, when an OnPush component is in the middle of render its state (class properties) should be stable, but the approach in your example breaks it because an observable value had been changed in the middle of render whereas its pointer `item$` stayed the same and for OnPush it meant no reason to rerender `async`.

Therefore possible solutions are:

- manually to tell angular that the component has been updated
- to cause changes when the component is stable
- to avoid onPush to let angular do the deep check to detect the changed observable value.

---

you can force check in `ngAfterContentInit` of the parent component once its content has been rendered and the component is stable.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  constructor(private iService: ItemsService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    item$ = this.iService.item$;

    ngAfterContentInit() { // <- add this
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxxiee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finner%2Finner.component.ts

---

If you don't want to use `ngAfterContentInit`, then you can defer emits making them being issued after all lifecycle hooks.

```js
    item$ = this.itemSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      delay(0),
    );
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v7upxo?file=src/app/services/items.service.ts

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: that's wrong. the issue is only in the emitted value. and to recommend setTimeout instead of rxjs is so so IMO.

Comment: use delay or anything else, that not a issue. i recommended setTimeout just to observe behavior. Not to do in code.

Comment: i have added this note in my answer.

Comment: No, even if change the value to different object, the same thing happens.

Comment: Please check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxxiee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finner%2Finner.component.ts focus on the input, then click the button.

Comment: @satanTime I am talking about changing the subject just in ngOnInit when no other actions are executed. In this example we emit clicks and focuses

Comment: I see, please check the example again, `ngAfterContentInit` is what you need.

Comment: I also dont think that this is good solution, then I need do the same thing all over components, because I dont know will someone else create loop in the app in the future. 
Why do you call sequentially detectChanges and then markForCheck?

Comment: the problem is in architecture because it has conflicts of priorities. That's why it requires a solution like that. To avoid it you need to change the architecture to provide data from top to bottom how flux pattern does for example, if you want the data to pop up then you need to use an (output) emitter. The sequence is exactly for causing rerender after broken priorities, first we need to detect changes what were missed and then to mark the component for check to cause a new rerender.

Comment: Added one more solution that requires update of the service, perhaps it fits your requirements better, simply add `delay(0)` into the pipe and then you don't need ngAfterContentInit.

Comment: I try to find solution without any hooks, delay(0) internally uses native timeouts. SO this is the same as just calling setTimeout. 
I just want to understand the reasons of why the view is not updated. I saw that markForCheck is called and tick function is called after that (by angular), so why the view is not updated.
I find this pretty common case, when we have many components and one of the parent ones watches observable and one of the child ones change it

Comment: And If it is a conflict of interests, why then simple actions works correctly, like clicking on button in the child. I do literally the same thing in them

Comment: as I wrote above - this approach has wrong data flow that causes conflicts of priorities. Looking forward to see a solution you like :)

Comment: when you click button your component is stable and angular can detect its changes. when parent component is rendered and something in the middle changes its state - it won't be detected, because usually data flow is from top to bottom. and to fix it you need to do hotfixes like above. Also in local env you should get an error that component state has been changed after check.

Comment: what is interesting though: when you subscribe to the observable and then assign the value to a variable which itself is bound in the template, it works.

Comment: yep, because the property of the component has been changed. in case of `items$` it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs, because you parent component needed your child component to initialize property before it can mark its view as initialized. Before parent's initialization could complete, you changed the value displayed in the template. That's why when you move to default strategy, you get expression has changed error.

For bypassing this put your value changing statement which is in ngOnInit into a setTimeout, so that first parent could complete its initialization then you emit that value.

Note :- I am saying setTimeout just to observe the behavior. Not as a solution.

Comment: Wrapping the statement in the setTimeout or whatever like that is equal to pressing a button or focusing an input
I didnt understand you answer. I dont display anything in the child component that is related to parent.

Comment: See your child component selector is inside parent component template right? So before Child complete its initialization of view parent can't complete its initialization of view. Before completion of view initialization of parent you changed a value that it had to display from child. Just google the error you are getting when you remove onpush. you will get it.

Comment: Yes, I understand the scoping and the reasons of why this error happens. But event thought I use OnPush and I see tick() function is called. So the question is more about Why the parent is not updated when the tick() function is called? I clearly saw that markForChecking was called before tick()

Comment: because the tick happened even before completion of first render.